# What is wrong with my C code? C code error

Tags: c

I am very new in C programming. can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code I am trying to run this code.

```
int main(void) 
{ char source[10]; 
char *dest; size_t i; 
strcpy(source, "0123456789"); 
dest = malloc(strlen(source)); 
for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++) { 
dest[i] = source [i]; 

} 

dest[i] = '\0'; 
printf("dest = %s", dest); return 0; 13. }
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Arrays are indexed from 0, not from 1. And why is there `13.` after the `return` statement?

Comment: `source` is not big enough to hold `"0123456789"`.

Comment: dest also is not big enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**, allocate enough memory for `source` to hold `0123456789`. And this `dest[i] = '\0';` causes **undefined behavior** as here you are trying to access(`dest[10]`) something which you didn't allocate. So allocate enough memory for `dest` to store `'\0'` at the end. For e.g

```
dest = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);/* +1 is for \0 char as strlen(source) doesn't include \0 */
```

**Secondly**, don't think that `source[0]` is integer zero `0` its a character zero i.e `'0'`(ascii - `48`). So you no need to start rotating form `i=1`, rotate from `i=0` and upto `'\0'`.

This

```
for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++) { /* array index starts from 0 */
      dest[i] = source [i]; 
}
```

Should be

```
for (i = 0;source[i]; i++) { /* when \0 encounters, loop terminates */
       dest[i] = source [i];
}
```

Comment: Upvote for `source[i]` as for-loop terminate condition.